# printing the date and time the data was inputted in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, module

In Python, I was working on a project and I want to know the time that I inputted something like a name, for example I have this piece of code:

```py
name = input("Please enter a name: ")
```

I also want to print the date and time that something was inputted in this variable .

What can I do?

Comment: Most likely you need a logging module with a proper format https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#displaying-the-date-time-in-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can create a variable `Logged_in =` and set it to `False`, as well as a time variable.

Once you've got both, set it for when the user clicks on the button (or input the thing you want) `logged_in = True` and 
something like that happens:

```py
import datetime
     if logged_in:
            time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

Then do whatever else you wanted to accomplish from there.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you dont need a boolean variable than you can just set it like so: 

login = input('login Y/N: ')

if login.upper() == "Y":
    time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    print(f'time:{time}')

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but the simplest way would be something like printing current datetime right before input like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.now())
name = input("Please enter a name: ")
```

If you want to actually store this data to use later, you can write your own input function:

```
from datetime import datetime

input_datetime_log = []

def input_with_datetime():
    input_datetime_log.append(datetime.now())
    return input()

name = input_with_datetime()
```

This way you gonna have `input_datetime_log` a `list` of `datetime` objects for each time `input_with_datetime` was called

Answer (score 0):

You could do right after the `input()` module use the time() module and then print that out.

If you wanted to save it for later use, you could save the file by by the open() function.
To put it all together, here it is:
 (sources: [time module](https://realpython.com/python-time-module), [opening and saving text](https://guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html))

```py
from time import time, ctime
t = time()
t = ctime(t)
f = open("time.txt","w+")
f.write(t)
f.close()
# Later...
f = open("time.txt", "r")
print(f)
f.close()
```